# How to reduce InfiniteProgress animation speed

Tags: codenameone

I'm currently using a custom image for animation, in place of the default.

I want the IP to rotate slowly, is there a way to change the animation speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

We'll add something like this:

```
/**
 * The animation rotates with EDT ticks, but not for every tick. To slow down the animation increase this
 * number and to speed it up reduce it to 1. It can't be 0 or lower.
 * @param tickCount the tickCount to set
 */
public void setTickCount(int tickCount);

/**
 * The angle to increase (in degrees naturally) in every tick count, reduce to 1 to make the animation perfectly
 * slow and smooth, increase to 45 to make it fast and jumpy. Its probably best to use a number that divides well
 * with 360 but that isn't a requirement. Valid numbers are anything between 1 and 359.
 * @param angleIncrease the angleIncrease to set
 */
public void setAngleIncrease(int angleIncrease);
```